# Reorder divs without using bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

Without using bootstrap library, how can i change the order of two divs. Is there any way

```
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='child-1'>Abc..</div>
 <div class='child-2'>Xyz..</div>
</div>
```

For mobile devices I want to show child 2 on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this CSS rule on `.parent` in a media query. This will reverse the order automatically and stack them vertically:

```css
.parent {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
 }
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='child-1'>Abc..</div>
 <div class='child-2'>Xyz..</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox with `flex-direction: column;` on the parent, then in your media query, use the `order` property to re-order the elements.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .child-2 {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
 <div class='child-1'>Abc..</div>
 <div class='child-2'>Xyz..</div>
</div>
```